# to select cell with specific part with disclosure button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In attached image for a cell, only the Gift option gets highlighted except the rest of cell and also disclosure button is not in its standard position. How it can be achieved, a cell only with particular selection and can i set the position of disclosure button also? Or is it button?

[image]

Comment: can you show code of set custom cell...? and it's subview.s

Comment: i just did nothing, i added only if statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath like if (indexPath.section==3)
    {
     // here its to be manage   
    } i think its button

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any background Image for your `TableViewCell` than use this delegate method of `UITableView`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

If you are using background Image for your `TableViewCell` than use this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UIImageView *selBGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urimage.png"]];
                cell.selectedBackgroundView = selBGView;
```

And for the position of discloser button you have to set autoResize property from IB file

Comment: what if i place button with disclosure image at cellForRowAtIndexPath so i can also get the blue highlight on selection?

Comment: Yes you can but it is the wrong way, and it will create other problem and will take too much time to fix those. UITableViewCell has its own property to do the same thing.